# Cómo puedo hacer para copiar en un array los datos de otro y eliminar del array original los elementos copiados en el nuevo array?

Tags: java, array, clone

Dado el siguiente código, lo que pretendo es, crear un array nuevo de 4 elementos a partir del que ya esta creado obteniendo de este los numeros impares y que los elementos que copio en el nuevo array los elimine del que esta definido, no soy capaz de conseguirlo y no consigo ver en donde esta el fallo, llevo horas peleando con el y pasando el debug de netbeans y no consigo ver en donde cometo el error, si me pudieseis hechar un cable, sobre todo en la parte "teorica" del fallo ya que no estoy entendiendo el fallo.
P.D: tengo que usar datos primitivos y no puedo usar listas, collections, etc.

```
    int[] numeros = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    int cantidadElementosNuevoArray = 4;

    int[] rangoResultado = new int[cantidadElementosNuevoArray];
    for (int i = 0; i < rangoResultado.length - 1; i++) {
        if (i% 2 == 0) {               
               rangoResultado[i] = numeros[i];                
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rangoResultado));
```

la salida que obtengo es:

`[1, 0, 3, 0]`

y la que pretendo conseguir sería:

`[1,3,5,7]`

y el array numeros que quedase tal que asi:

`[2,4,6,8,9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > la salida que obtengo es: [1, 0, 3, 0]

**¿Por qué dio esa salida?**

Al momento de crear el objeto donde estará el arreglo de enteros:

```java
int[] rangoResultado = new
int[cantidadElementosNuevoArray];
```

El arreglo se inicializa a `0`, esto quiere decir, cada elemento del arreglo, su valor por defecto será `0`.

Sin embargo, el problema real está en esta condición:

```java
rangoResultado.length - 1
```

En la cual solo ejecutará iteraciones de `0` a `2` (debido a que el tamaño del arreglo `rangoResultado` es `4`, como le restaste `-1`, dará como resultado `3`, por lo tanto, la variable `i` únicamente podrá tomar esos valores). Entonces ya sabemos porque nos dio como resultado `[1,0,3,0]` y esto se debe porque solo estas tomando en cuenta estos tres índices: `0`,`1`,`2`. El último elemento del arreglo `rangoResultado` tendrá un valor `0` almacenado, debido a que, el bucle solo hace iteraciones de `0` a `2`.

Además hay otro error y es en esta condición:

```java
i% 2 == 0
```

Estás evaluando si el valor que tenga `i` es par, cuando en realidad se debería detectar si el elemento del arreglo `numeros` es impar.

La condición debería estar de esta forma:

```java
numeros[i] % 2 != 0
```

Si el residuo del número es `1`, es porque es impar.

**Solución al problema:** Necesitas crear una variable llamada `pos`, en la cual guardaremos la posición del arreglo `rangoResultado` y esto se debe porque no podemos usar la variable `i` en el arreglo `rangoResultado`, ya que estaríamos desbordando el arreglo y daría una excepción.

Es decir, si hiciéramos esto:

```java
int[] numeros = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int cantidadElementosNuevoArray = 4;
int[] rangoResultado = new int[cantidadElementosNuevoArray];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) 
{
    if (numeros[i] % 2 != 0)            
        rangoResultado[i] = numeros[i];                
}       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rangoResultado));
```

Daría la excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`, debido a que, el índice máximo que puede tener `rangoResultado` es `3`.

Entonces, la solución es usar otra variable, en la cual se vaya incrementando cada vez que se detecta si un elemento del arreglo `numeros` es impar.

**Solución completa:**

```java
public class Program 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        int pos = 0;
        int[] numeros = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        int cantidadElementosNuevoArray = 4;

        int[] rangoResultado = new int[cantidadElementosNuevoArray];
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) 
        {
            if (numeros[i] % 2 != 0) 
            {               
                rangoResultado[pos] = numeros[i]; 
                ++pos;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rangoResultado));
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la explicacion!! y la solucion perfect!;)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que estas haciendo la validación dentro del if del valor de i no del valor asociado dentro del arreglo de números. De acuerdo a lo anterior el código seria así:

```
int[] numeros = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

int cantidadElementosNuevoArray = 4;

int[] rangoResultado = new int[cantidadElementosNuevoArray];
for (int i = 0; i < rangoResultado.length - 1; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] % 2 != 0) {               
           rangoResultado[i] = numeros[i];                
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rangoResultado));
```

Fijate bien en el if que te estoy mostrando dentro del ejemplo, además que la validación de que el numero sea impar es que el modulo sea diferente a 0, no igual.

Quedo atento a cualquier comentario del mismo.

Comment: eso mismo ya lo habia probado, y me ocurre lo mismo, me da la misma salida, lo de comprobar en el if el valor de i y no del elemento, asi como no poner igual a 0, es porque lo que pretendia era sacar los valores por posicion y no por valor del elemento, gracias por la yuda y tomarte tu tiempo en la respuesta, pero seguimos igual ;)

Comment: Estaba revisando el código y veo que estas recorriendo dado al nuevo arreglo que creaste, que tiene un tamaño de 4, no estas recorriendo el arreglo números, por lo que al momento de realizar la validación en la posición 2 por ejm, lo deja vacio. La opción que veo es que tienes que hacer dos for, uno para recorrer el arreglo de numeros y otro para llenar el nuevo arreglo.